# How can I save uint16 NumPy arrays with JPEG compression, and load uint16 JPEG compressed data?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, uint16

If I have a NumPy array with `dtype=np.uint16`, how can I save the data as `uint16` JPEG compressed?

How can I then load the `uint16` JPEG compressed data?

It doesn't seem like Pillow supports this, at least not by saving the file as `jpg` extension, see [Pillow image file formats](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg).

Comment: Consider using PNG or TIFF or PGM/PNM for 16-bit data.

Answer (score 3):

You can't save 16-bit images in (plain old) [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) format. Only 8-bit and 12-bit are allowed (see ISO/IEC 10918-1). You might look into [JPEG 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000), which also supports 16-bit.

[Pillow has JPEG 2000 support](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg-2000). Unfortunately, I wasn't able to save a 16-bit RGB image. Best I could do, was a 16-bit grayscale image:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image_array = np.uint16(np.random.rand(200, 200) * 65535)
image_pil = Image.fromarray(image_array, 'I;16')
image_pil.save('image_pil.jp2')
```

Opening `image_pil.jp2` in GIMP indeed shows a 16-bit grayscale image.

Since you already have a NumPy array, [OpenCV](http://www.opencv.org) comes to mind, whose [`cv2.imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) method also has JPEG 2000 support. Using OpenCV, I was able to also save a 16-bit RGB image:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_array = np.uint16(np.random.rand(200, 200, 3) * 65535)
cv2.imwrite('image_cv.jp2', image_array)
```

And, opening `image_cv.jp2` in GIMP shows a 16-bit RGB image.

By default, OpenCV disables JPEG 2000 support. You have to explicitly set the environment variable `OPENCV_IO_ENABLE_JASPER=1`.

Alternatively, you could go for (compressed) PNG.

Hope that helps!

Comment: the [Pillow has JPEG 2000 support](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg-2000) link you shared doesn't mention support for 'uint16'.  Are you certain it's correctly supported?  Also, I'm not familiar with the notation `I;16` & don't see it in the [pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).  I'm guessing it's specifying signed 16 bit integers.  Can you explain it and provide a link to where it's defined?

Comment: It appears OpenCV [doesn't support compression with JPEG 2000](https://answers.opencv.org/question/176706/did-jpeg-2000-saved-in-lossless-or-lossy/)

Comment: @user3731622 Regarding Pillow: In the [`PIL.Image.fromarray`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) method, there's the `mode` parameter, where you can choose one these [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes). There you can see, that `I;16` is "16-bit unsigned integer pixels". As mentioned, I couldn't get three channel 16-bit unsigned working. Regarding OpenCV: If that's true in respect of Jasper, then you're right, there's no compression. Maybe compressed PNG is the way to go then.